# Cannot get my morris charts to work without errors

Tags: javascript, morris.js

I've searched and searched and read and read and tried and tried.  I must be missing something because implementing this feature is eluding me.
Therefore I'm posting hoping to solicit some suggestions.
I also realize Morris chart is no longer supported but it what was assigned to me so I'm doing my best.
Here are the errors:

```
morris-0.5.1.min.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at d.<anonymous> (morris-0.5.1.min.js:6)
    at d.<anonymous> (morris-0.5.1.min.js:6)
    at d.b.Grid.d.setData (morris-0.5.1.min.js:6)
    at d [as constructor] (morris-0.5.1.min.js:6)
    at d.c [as constructor] (morris-0.5.1.min.js:6)
    at new d (morris-0.5.1.min.js:6)
    at Object.d [as Area] (morris-0.5.1.min.js:6)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (proc-totals-chartX.php:194)
    at j (jquery-2.1.1.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-2.1.1.js:2)
```

And here is my function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    Morris.Area({
        element: 'ChartArea',
        data: [
            { y: '2017/01', ortiz: 155, curiel: 32, covarrubias: 20, castillo: 3 },
            { y: '2017/02', ortiz: 130, curiel: 25, covarrubias: 20, castillo: 6 },
            { y: '2017/03', ortiz: 186, curiel: 44, covarrubias: 61, castillo: 4 },
            { y: '2017/04', ortiz: 165, curiel: 29, covarrubias: 60, castillo: 5 },
            { y: '2017/05', ortiz: 182, curiel: 11, covarrubias: 40, castillo: 8, montalvo: 12 },
            { y: '2017/06', ortiz: 198, curiel: 9,  covarrubias: 58, castillo: 13, montalvo: 18 }
        ],
        xkey: ['y'],
        ykey: ['ortize','curiel','covarrubias','castillo','montalvo'],
        labels: ['Ortiz', 'Curiel', 'Covarrubias', 'Castillo', 'Montalvo']
    });
});
```

And I've tried to research each and every description.  I still don't have an answer. So any pointers, suggestions, resolutions will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Set `yKey` in the plural form - `yKeys`.

**[JS Bin Example](https://jsbin.com/beqoyebinu/edit?html,js,output)**

Your code which works

```js
Morris.Area({
    element: 'area-example',
    data: [
        { y: '2017/01', ortiz: 155, curiel: 32, covarrubias: 20, castillo: 3 },
        { y: '2017/02', ortiz: 130, curiel: 25, covarrubias: 20, castillo: 6 },
        { y: '2017/03', ortiz: 186, curiel: 44, covarrubias: 61, castillo: 4 },
        { y: '2017/04', ortiz: 165, curiel: 29, covarrubias: 60, castillo: 5 },
        { y: '2017/05', ortiz: 182, curiel: 11, covarrubias: 40, castillo: 8, montalvo: 12 },
        { y: '2017/06', ortiz: 198, curiel: 9,  covarrubias: 58, castillo: 13, montalvo: 18 }
    ],
    xkey: 'y',
    ykeys: ['ortize','curiel','covarrubias','castillo','montalvo'],
    labels: ['Ortiz', 'Curiel', 'Covarrubias', 'Castillo', 'Montalvo']
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css">
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
 <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="area-example" style="height: 250px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```